# SSIS How to Get it Running

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis

I apologize that this is a dumb question, but I have been pulling my hair out on it all day.

We are running SSIS, and I need to make a tiny modification to the query. However, I have never actually used it before. (I know my way around SQL just fine.)

The guy who normally does it is up to his eyeballs in other stuff, so I am filling in. However, when I open the project in VS2008 it says for the Package.dtsx file "Unable to laod this document ... To install Integration Servcies run SQL Server Setup and Select Integration Services".

However, when I run the SQL Server 2k8R2 set up program there is not "integration Services" option. I also plugged in my VS2008 Pro CD and there was nothing like it on there either.

How do I get set up to work with SSIS designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be on the feature selection page. See the MSN article [How to: Install SQL Server 2008 R2 (Setup)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx)

Douglas Laudenschlager has this screen shot on the article [Expanded "Feature Selection" page in the SQL Server 2008 Setup Wizard](http://dougbert.com/blogs/dougbert/archive/2008/05/15/expanded-quot-feature-selection-quot-page-in-the-sql-server-2008-setup-wizard.aspx)

Be sure to select Management Tools to get the tools you're looking for

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's Business Intelligence Development Studio that needs to be installed for SSIS tools.  I tried all the other options 1 by 1 and that was the one that finally did it.